# How to get the address on clicking in the google map?

Tags: apex, visualforce

Is it possible to get the address and pin code in the billing address field in account object from google maps when the user clicks on the map.If the user clicks on different address it should get updated with that address.

Comment: That should be possible, on click of any address you can have a confirmation for updating Account. What challenges are you are facing?

Comment: I had a requirement to get the address auto filled in the billing address  after clicking in the map. could you help me by providing any example regarding that

Comment: Share what you have tried so far

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I have put together a simple solution using Google Map API. Here I am passing the value of Latitude and Longitude from click event on the map to the Google Maps Geocoding API and it is returning me the address of the location in JSON format. In the JSON, there are different address_components available as mentioned below. I am using these values to populate new account address.

```
"types": [ "street_number" ] // Street No
"types": [ "route" ] // Street Name
"types": [ "administrative_area_level_1", "political" ]// the state
"types" : [ "locality", "political" ]//the city
"types": [ "postal_code" ] //Zip code
```

You have to pass an account ID to see the result.

VF Page

```
<apex:page standardController="Account" > 
    <script type="text/javascript" src="https://maps.google.com/maps/api/js?sensor=false"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1/jquery.min.js"></script>    
    <style>
        #map {
          font-family: Arial;
          font-size:12px;
          line-height:normal !important;
          height:250px;
          background:transparent;
        }
    </style>    
    <apex:form id="accountform" >
        <apex:pageBlock id="accountblock">
            <apex:pageBlockSection title="Account details">
                <apex:outputField Value="{!Account.Name}"/>
            </apex:pageBlockSection>
            <apex:pageBlockSection id="addressblocksection" title="Address details" columns="2">
                <apex:inputField id="BillingStreet" value="{!Account.BillingStreet}" />
                <apex:inputField id="BillingCity" value="{!Account.BillingCity}" />
                <apex:inputField id="BillingState" value="{!Account.BillingState}" />
                <apex:inputField id="BillingPostalCode" value="{!Account.BillingPostalCode}" />
                <apex:inputField id="BillingCountry" value="{!Account.BillingCountry}" />
            </apex:pageBlockSection>
        </apex:pageBlock>
        <div id="map">Hello</div> 
        <script type="text/javascript">
            $(document).ready(function() {
                var map;
                var marker;             
                var myOptions = {
                    zoom: 15,
                    mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP,
                    mapTypeControl: false
                }                
                var geocoder = new google.maps.Geocoder();
                var address = "{!JSENCODE(Account.BillingStreet)}, " + "{!JSENCODE(Account.BillingCity)}, " + "{!JSENCODE(Account.BillingPostalCode)}, " + "{!JSENCODE(Account.BillingCountry)}";
                address = address.replace(/(\r\n|\n|\r)/gm,"");
                geocoder.geocode( { address: address}, function(results, status) {
                    if (status == google.maps.GeocoderStatus.OK && results.length) {
                        if (status != google.maps.GeocoderStatus.ZERO_RESULTS) {
                            //create map
                            map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById("map"), myOptions);
                            //center map
                            map.setCenter(results[0].geometry.location);
                            //create marker
                            marker = new google.maps.Marker({
                                position: results[0].geometry.location,
                                map: map,
                                title: "{!Account.Name}"
                            });
                            //add listeners
                            google.maps.event.addListener(map, 'click', function(event) {
                              geocoder.geocode({'latLng': event.latLng},function(results, status){
                                  if (status == google.maps.GeocoderStatus.OK && results.length) {
                                      result=results[0].address_components;
                                      var info=[];
                                      for(var i=0;i<result.length;++i){
                                        if(result[i].types[0]=="street_number"){
                                            info.push(result[i].long_name);
                                        }
                                        if(result[i].types[0]=="route"){
                                            info.push(result[i].long_name);
                                            document.getElementById('{!$Component.accountform.accountblock.addressblocksection.BillingStreet}').value = info.join(' ');
                                        }
                                        if(result[i].types[0]=="locality"){
                                            document.getElementById('{!$Component.accountform.accountblock.addressblocksection.BillingCity}').value = result[i].long_name;
                                        }
                                        if(result[i].types[0]=="administrative_area_level_1"){
                                            document.getElementById('{!$Component.accountform.accountblock.addressblocksection.BillingState}').value = result[i].long_name;
                                        }
                                        if(result[i].types[0]=="country"){
                                            document.getElementById('{!$Component.accountform.accountblock.addressblocksection.BillingCountry}').value = result[i].long_name;
                                        }
                                        if(result[i].types[0]=="postal_code"){
                                            document.getElementById('{!$Component.accountform.accountblock.addressblocksection.BillingPostalCode}').value = result[i].long_name;
                                        }                                       
                                      }
                                  }
                              });
                            });                         
                        }
                    }else{
                        $('#map').css({'height' : '15px'});
                        $('#map').html("Oops! {!Account.Name}'s billing address could not be found, please make sure the address is correct.");
                    }
                });
            });
        </script>
    </apex:form>
</apex:page>
```

Screen 1 Current Account Location

[image]

Screen 2 Location changed after clicking on a different area

[image]

Comment: Thanks.This is working fine.But cant we able to change in account directly.

Comment: What do you mean by "change in account directly"?

Comment: once after the account is created with billing address .if we add the google map in the related list if we click on the map then it should change directly in the billing address of account not in the page blocksection which we have created

Comment: What is the use case? Even if you add the VF page to Account layout, it will not be visible in edit mode. In detail mode you can try to hardcode IDs of the address elements but Salesforce can change their page structure or naming conventions at any time, so it's not a good idea to hard code ID's.

Comment: how to get the map without passing the account id.

Comment: Account ID is not required to create the MAP. It is the address (here it is billing address) that is required to put the place in center of the MAP.

Comment: but if i m not passing account id i can't able to see the map.it is throwing the error

Comment: Please study the code. You are getting error because of the address variable. It is not getting created as Account ID is not available.

Comment: on selecting the place in the map can we get the electoral constituency of a selected place.

Comment: @SarojBera do you can help me? please, https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/253248/i-can-not-call-api-google-maps-in-visualforce-page